# Modules and namespaces

Tags: 7

I have strange problem or maybe I'm doing something wrong. I've create my own module. My .info file looks like this:

```
...
files[] = DdFactory.inc
files[] = ArticleManager.inc
...
```

In `ArticleManager.inc` I have class ArticleManager (no namespace). Than I would like to use DFactory (namespace Dd) class in ArticleManager.

Here is the beginning of DFactory.inc:

```
<?php

namespace Dd;

class Factory
{
...
```

In ArticleManger I have:

```
$ob = new \Dd\Factory();
```

And error:

```
Fatal error:  Class 'Dd\Factory' not found
```

I can make it work in two ways. Or I have to remove namespaces than `$ob = new Factory();` or I have to add `include 'DFactory.inc'` at top of ArticleManager.inc

Could somebody tells me how to run it with namespaces and without the include? I'm using drupal 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the xautoload (http://drupal.org/project/xautoload) module to help with autoloading. It's faster and less fragile then the D7 core code registry.

XAutoload implements the PSR-0 standard, which is how Drupal 8 will handle namespaces, so it's the most future proof way.

Answer (score 1):

The code registry does not support namespaces, so far. I tried adding the following code to the classes.php a module of mine declares in its .info file.

```
class codetesting {
  protected $file;
}

namespace code;

class testing {
  protected $file;
}
```

Looking at the "registry" table, I noticed the namespace is not used. This means that when I try to create an instance of `\code\testing`, Drupal does not find the file containing its definition, as the registry contains information for the `testing` class.

What you can do is altering the registry table to include the namespace in the "name" column.